# No such element filesrc after installing Gstreamer

Tags: windows, gstreamer

I'm new to Gstreamer. I installed Gstreamer and found that "filesrc" element is missing right after the installation (using `gst-inspect-1.0`). If I type in `gst-inspect-1.0 filesrc`, it returns "No such element or plugin"

My environment:

- Windows10 x64
- Gstreamer v1.16.1
- [Gstreamer MSVC 64-bit installer (runtime and development)](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/)
- "Complete" is selected for both installers

My original goal is camera capturing by OpenCV+Gstreamer, and my vs2019 project keeps returning "no element v4l2src". I finally found that even "filesrc" is not available, which means I already have problems BEFORE I build OpenCV together with Gstreamer.

I checked [this installation guide](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-windows.html) too but no luck. Are there some additional steps to install the plugins?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652098/gstreamer-filesrc-plugin-missing-to-interact-with-vlc-in-fedora-centos-ubuntu/5653875#5653875), I should delete the gstreamer "registry" to force it to kind of re-detect the available functions. This solution is for linux, not Windows 10. But I finally found the absolute path of that registry, fortunately:

```
C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\gstreamer-1.0\registry.x86_64.bin
```

What I did to get "filesrc" appears in the list and available:

```
1. Delete the registry file manually
2. Performed a clean re-install
3. Run "gst-inspect-1.0"
```

Hope my workaround helps someone who gets stuck in the same situation.